# extracting double value using NSRange

Tags: objective-c, substring, nsrange

I have a string "Number: 0.3456" 
How can I remove the "Number: " part to extract the double value "0.3456" from it using `NSRange`?

Answer (score 1):

If `Number: X.XXX` is a fixed pattern you simply can do something like

```
NSString * string = @"Number: 0.3456";
NSString * prefix = @"Number: ";
NSString * doubleString = [string substringFromIndex:prefix.length];
double yourDouble = [doubleString doubleValue];
```

if you really want to use `NSRange` you could do something like

```
NSString * string = @"Number: 0.3456";
NSString * substringToRemove = @"Number: ";
NSRange substringRange = [string rangeOfString:substringToRemove];
NSString * doubleString = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:substringRange 
                                                          withString:@""];
double yourDouble = [doubleString doubleValue];
```

The main difference is that the second example will remove *every* occurrence of the `Number:` string from the original one, whereas the first will just remove the prefix.

Comment: my bad, I forgot that `NSRange` is a plain C struct. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [NSScanner scanDouble:]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an NSScanner, as long as you set the scan location first:

```
double result;
NSString *str = @"Number: 0.3456";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];

[scanner setScanLocation:[@"Number: " length]];
[scanner scanDouble:&result];
```

Remember that `scanDouble:` returns `YES` or `NO` to indicate whether a scan was successful or not.